# Transferring files via Skype using Windows API

Tags: c#, skype4com

Is there a way I can receive and transfer a file over Skype using skype4com and the Windows API (user32.dll)? Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

This [topic](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=700343) over at skype suggests it is not possible to do this in an automated fashion using the public Skype API.

You can open a file transfer dialog; after that it is out of your hands.

Comment: well..isn't there another way?

Comment: how to open the file transfer dialog? i mean how to give accept to an incoming file?